# Showing/hiding nested checkboxes - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have 4 checkboxes:

```
<form name="form" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="1" data-target="sub">1
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="two" value="2" class="hidden sub">2
        <br>    
        <input type="checkbox" name="three" value="3" class="hidden sub" data-target="subsub">3
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="four" value="4" class="hidden subsub">4
</form>

<style>
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script>
    $('input').change(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var data = that.data('target');
    if(data) { 
        that.parent('form').children("."+data).toggleClass('hidden');
    }
</script>
```

When the first get checked. The 2nd and 3rd become visible (toggleClass('hidden')). This is fairly simple. But when you check the 3rd, the 4th must becomes visible(toggleClass('hidden'). The 2nd does not have any visual effect.

The problem is: when you uncheck the 1st, the 3 checkboxes must become invisible, even is the 4th is visible by the check 3rd box.

I don't really seem how this is possible with just the hidden class?

JSFIDDLE [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/2m2w2hkp/)

### EDIT

This has to be an universal solution. I generate the HTML and would like to solve this with a universal javascript without needing to write specific names (variables) in the script.
The only thing I can do is different classes to the levels. So only to groups (1), (2, 3), (4).

I also can't use the value of the checkboxes, because the checkboxes can be check or not and still have to hide an element. There is no linearity here...

Comment: Do you have control over the rendered HTML? Meaning, can you add different class/data-target values to the nodes? For example: data-target="1", data-target="1.1" ...

Comment: I can, do you know how to resolve the problem then, because I still dont see a sulution then.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the input `.is(':checked')` and use `.hide()` and `.show()` while using `.trigger('change')`.  this way you can keep your original HTML structure

demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/2m2w2hkp/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        console.log(that.data('target'));
        var data = that.data('target');
        if(data) { 
            data = "."+data;
            if (that.is(':checked')) {
                that.parent('form').children(data).show();
            }
            else {
                that.parent('form').children(data).prop('checked', false);
                that.parent('form').children(data).trigger('change');
                that.parent('form').children(data).hide();
            }
        }
        console.log(data);        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use .find() if it's the top-level one (either add an ID or use the data-target)?

Something like (if the top checkbox has the id "checkbox1":

```js
if (that.attr("id") == "checkbox1")
{
    that.parent("form").find("input").each(function(){
     if ($(this).attr("id") != "checkbox1")
     {
      $(this).addClass("hidden");
     }
    });
}
```

Without testing it, if checkbox1 is checked, it adds the "hidden" class to the all of the input elements in the form without adding it to "checkbox1"

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, Ive added a little bit more detail to the question. I cannot add id's and can't create a specific script for an item. But I got an idea from your example!

Comment: oh you can use if (!hasClass("hidden")) and is(":checked") to determine if the top-level button checkbox was unchecked.
Then go through the descendants with find(), and hide them if (hasClass("hidden"))
Glad I could help a little!